# Django constraints: if foreignkey is empty, then field must be true

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm reading Django's [documentation on CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/) to avoid overriding the .save() method to achieve this behavior:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    is_default = models.BooleanField()

if m.user is None and m.is_default -> valid
if m.user is None and not m.is_default -> invalid
if m.user is not None and m.is_default -> invalid
if m.user is not None and not m.is_default -> valid
```

Basically, I want is_default to be true only if user is assigned.

Can I do this with `CheckConstraint` or am I forced to override the .save() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
models.CheckConstraint(
    check=(models.Q(is_default=True, user__isnull=True) | models.Q(is_default=False, user__isnull=False)),
    name='...')
```